# Is Linux Standard Base (LSB) AppChecker reliable?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-standard-base

According to the LSB scanner, my binary is supposedly incompatible with a specific version of Linux because it uses GBLICXX_3.4.9 symbols. But when I tried to run the binary myself on that version, everything seems to work fine...

Can a binary even start on a Linux distro if that distro is missing the runtime libraries containing the required symbols?

Comment: How did you test whether that symbol actually was available on the machine you tested on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I've understood well the question but as far as I know even though you have compiled your program with a modern glibc does not necessarily mean that you won't be able to execute into an older version. The next Linux command:

`objdump -T "your exe or lib file" | grep GLIB`

will show you which version of the glibc the symbols of your program belong to.

For further information there is a paper called [How to write shared libraries](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) by Ulrich Drepper that explains a lot of things of how symbols work in linux not only for shared libraries but also for executables

Answer (score 3):

I suspect they're warning you that you're using symbols that, even if they are available on your test system, may not be available on all LSB-compliant systems.

Comment: That is _exactly_ what the warning means. +1